# How can I connect two objects from different windows in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, parent-child, qpushbutton

I have a `window1` which has 2 buttons, one <kbd>add</kbd> button and a <kbd>next</kbd> button.

The <kbd>add</kbd> button is initially disabled. Once clicked on <kbd>next</kbd> button, a new `window2` is opened.
On that window there is a <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

I want to enable the <kbd>add</kbd> button from `window1` after clicking on the <kbd>OK</kbd> button from `window2`.

Is it possible to connect two objects ( signal & slot ) from diffrent windows ? If yes, where ( on which `.cpp` file ) do I have to write the connect function ?

Comment: Add more detail. Which of the windows is signal and slot? You will probably need a third .cpp file to store these, or you'll have to provide more detail about the code behind each of the windows.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can connect a signal from one object to a slot in a different object - otherwise the functionality wouldn't be very useful.

You can either do the connection outside either object in some code that has access to both, or you can pass a pointer of/to one of the objects to the other and then do the connection inside the other object. What makes the most sense depends on how your code is structured.